# Powershell error - Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell with SharePoint and I found this simple powershell example

```
$timers = (Get-SPTimerJob | ($_.isDisabled -eq $false) )  
$timers
```

And I get this error

> Expressions are only allowed as the
>   first element of a pipeline.

Can you explain the error/How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$timers = Get-SPTimerJob | where-object { $_.isDisabled -eq $false }
$timers
```

Just a little bit of syntax error. Get-SPTimerJob needs to be piped to 'something', the where clause (short hand '?'), and use curly braces {} instead of round braces ().

You can use "?" as an alias for where-object, but for production scripts it's recommended to keep the full command names.

Comment: @x0n, why would you not recommend using aliases?

Comment: it's mainly for readability. It's not that big of a sin to use the built-in aliases, but you wouldn't want to use custom aliases for production scripts as this kills portability. Aliases are best used as an aid for interactive use to cut down on typing, or for one-off throwaway scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like:

```
$timers = Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.isDisabled -eq $false }
```